# Is there a way for Airflow DockerOperator specify worker to create container

Tags: docker, airflow

I have an airflow cluster of about 10 machines. Is there are way that I can specify a DAG to be executed on a specific machine, say 'worker06'?

Here's my current DAG code:

```
t1 = BashOperator(task_id="print_dag_starts", bash_command="echo 'Dag starts at:'", dag=dag)
t2 = BashOperator(task_id="print_start_time", bash_command="date", dag=dag)
t3 = DockerOperator(
    docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
    command="/bin/sleep 30",
    image="ubuntu:latest",
    network_mode="bridge",
    task_id="start_test_ubuntu_docker",
    dag=dag
)
t4 = BashOperator(task_id="print_dag_finishes", bash_command="echo 'Dag finishes at:'", dag=dag)
t5 = BashOperator(task_id="print_end_time", bash_command="date", dag=dag)

t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4 >> t5
```

When I try to change docker_url to "10.18.12.29:2376" which is the hostname in the cluster, airflow pops error:

It tells:

> docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.18.12.29', port=2376): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7546917a30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))